# Receive Firebase silent notifcation on Android when notifcations for that app are off

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, silentpush

I am in process of developing off-line event logging system with firebase Push notifications. I have implemented the silent push and it works on IOS even if the notifications for that app are turned off. 
Will android act the same way as IOS, where silent notifications will be received, regardless of user settings ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that on iOS/Android, maybe on iOS you are not using Apple's APNS to deliver the messages but the Firebase messaging system which requires your app to be running to receive them.

On Android it should be similar but working against the user's will is not encouraged.

Comment: *I don't think you can do that on iOS/Android* he already has it up and running in ios

Comment: I also explained the one option I know to do it but I won't call that a push notification.

Comment: We need to send offline events back to firebase for UAC campaigns. Hence running this service. It works similarly to how Instant messaging systems would fire off notification when a user has a new message.It may not be direct push notification, but it operates on the exact same logic. We also looked into a server side solution however firebase does not seem to support event logging server side.

Comment: By "We need to send offline events back to firebase for UAC campaigns", you mean that the android/iOS app should send messages to the Firebase server (FCM)? Maybe you are talking about upstream messages (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream)? Because in that case it makes sense.